# Favourite questions and answers from the 2nd quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

We'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from April 1st 2017 through June 30th 2017.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2017-04..2017-06) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2017-04..2017-06). Since we currently get ~1.3k/1.8k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 2nd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/692961)
- [Questions with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/692963)
- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/692965)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. There's also no requirement to only mention one post per meta answer, since this is **not a contest** of any kind. Just list as many and whatever posts you want. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2876/49)**.

Answer (score 5):

I think that these pairings of Question and Answer represent some of the best we can hope for here at Movies and TV.

[Why did Vader passively accept being killed and replaced at Palpatine's command?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74701/why-did-vader-passively-accept-being-killed-and-replaced-at-palpatines-command)

I really like the analysis that @F1Krazy put into this one

---

[Why does Quentin Tarantino add non-plot related dialogue in his movies?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75191/why-does-quentin-tarantino-add-non-plot-related-dialogue-in-his-movies)*

<sup>* I'm obviously biased on this one</sup>

---

[Why did they pick World War I over World War II in Wonder Woman?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74337/why-did-they-pick-world-war-i-over-world-war-ii-in-wonder-woman)

@AJ did a great job of finding a relevant quote to @AnkitSharma's highly topical question.

Answer (score 3):

As, mentioning our own answer is also allowed, I would like to add my answer as one of the favourite answers.

[What's this episode in the Pokémon anime and why wasn't Pikachu with ash?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68867/whats-this-episode-in-the-pok%c3%a9mon-anime-and-why-wasnt-pikachu-with-ash/72195#72195)

I added direct reference from the episode and a detailed analysis with respect to Pokémon on why Pikachu was not used in the Pokémon battle.

@Paulie_D and Ankit Sharma wrote great answers to the [Mycroft Job](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/what-is-mycrofts-job) question.

[This](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/what-is-mycrofts-job/75037#75037) is Ankit Sharma's answer and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75035/what-is-mycrofts-job/75038#75038) is Paulie_D's answer. Paulie_D gave answer from multiple sources and Ankit gave it directly from the episode.