# Rewards for the best answer from the 2nd quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-1st-quarter-of-2017) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2872/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2017), I'd ask the community again for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from April 1st 2017 through June 30th 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/693555/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2017-04-01&Count=1300)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from anyone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 30th July 2017.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

## Results:-

**Winner - [Thunderforge](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71823/why-are-there-so-few-movies-about-the-vietnam-war-itself/71829#71829)

1st Runner-up - [Flater](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75487/why-is-the-spoken-german-in-many-us-films-and-tv-shows-so-inaccurate/75492#75492)

2nd Runner-up - [A J](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75534/who-was-the-oldest-actor-to-play-a-teenager/75556#75556)**

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would like to nominate Thunderforge's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71823/why-are-there-so-few-movies-about-the-vietnam-war-itself/71829#71829) to [Why are there so few movies about the Vietnam war itself?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/71823/48608)

The answer gave reasons along with a nice analysis quoting a research article by a respected historian.

Answer (score 7):

I would like to nominate [Flater](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22424/flater)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75492/27264) to [Why is the spoken German in many US films and TV shows so inaccurate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75487/27264)

This answer has provided nice analysis of this question with three different reasonings.

Comment: IMHO it missed a very important point, so much so that I felt compelled to make another answer. Still, a well written answer, just ... err... a bit lacking. You could say it was just me, but it looks like at least 7 other people felt the same (if not for the same reason).

Answer (score 6):

I am nominating [**AJ**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264/a-j)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75534/who-was-the-oldest-actor-to-play-a-teenager/75556#75556) to **Who was the oldest actor to play a teenager?**

AJ had the best answer.  Enough said.

Comment: Of the candidates, this is the only one I'd actually already upvoted. I'm not sure I'd hold it up as a shining example of a great answer, but it was at least correct, and better than the other answers to the question.

Answer (score 4):

I am nominating [**dannie**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/18076/dannie)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71026/how-did-tyler-durden-know-all-of-the-useful-information-that-he-knew/71065#71065) to **How did Tyler Durden know all of the useful information that he knew?**

This answer provided insight from the user who answered the question as well as references and sources from the film.

Answer (score 3):

I am nominating [**Paulie_D**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317/paulie-d)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74476/why-is-edward-in-a-white-limousine-at-the-end-of-the-film/74481#74481) to **Why is Edward in a white limousine at the end of the film?**

Paulie_D provided sources, quotes and his own insight to answer the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to nominate F1Krazy's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/74711/34317) to [Why did Vader passively accept being killed and replaced at Palpatine's command?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/74701/why-did-vader-passively-accept-being-killed-and-replaced-at-palpatines-command/74711#74711)

A detailed analysis richly derserving the massive upvote storm it received.

Answer (score 2):

I am nominating [**Rand al'Thor**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27759/rand-althor)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71864/how-does-eddard-stark-know-that-bran-saw-cersei-and-jaime-together/71869#71869) to **How does Eddard Stark know that Bran saw Cersei and Jaime together?**

This answer provided an in-depth explanation from the user as well as quotes and sources.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [gabe3886](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/20991/gabe3886)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/72248/27264) to [Captain America… why is he unbeatable..?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/72247/27264)

This answer has provided nice analysis about a character.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [S S](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48608/s-s)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75090/1190) to [Why Kilimanjaro song not shot at Mt Kilimanjaro location?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75086/why-kilimanjaro-song-not-shot-at-mt-kilimanjaro-location)

This answer is pretty detailed and based on good analysis and didn't got as much appreciation as it deserved.