# Rewards for the best answer from the 3rd quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-2nd-quarter-of-2017) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4014/favourite-questions-and-answers-from-the-3rd-quarter-of-2017), I'd ask the community again for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward of appreciation:

**Please link to an answer which was created from July 1st 2017 through September 30th 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple entries submit individual answers for each post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/736918/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2017-07-01&Count=1450)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from anyone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 25th October 2017.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

## Results:-

**Winner - [Kevin Troy](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/76404/1190)

1st Runner-up - [Gustavo Gabriel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78507/1190)

2nd Runner-up - [A J](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80524/how-did-they-film-the-walks-between-the-twin-towers-in-the-walk/80525#80525)**

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll add [Kevin Troy's answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/76404/34317) to [Why were certain shots deliberately paced slowly in 2001: A Space Odyssey?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76381/why-were-certain-shots-deliberately-paced-slowly-in-2001-a-space-odyssey/76404#76404)

A great piece of analysis.

We need more of this.

Answer (score 5):

I am nominating Gustavo Gabriel 's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78505/is-the-face-on-the-front-of-the-truck-a-marvel-approved-likeness-of-the-green-go/78507#78507) to [Is the face on the front of the truck a Marvel approved likeness of the Green Goblin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/78505/is-the-face-on-the-front-of-the-truck-a-marvel-approved-likeness-of-the-green-go)

This answer provided a great source that answered the question.

Answer (score 4):

I am nominating AJ's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/80525/1190) to [How did they film the walks between the Twin Towers in The Walk?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/80524/how-did-they-film-the-walks-between-the-twin-towers-in-the-walk)

A good detailed answer with proper backing.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate [Steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/steelersquirrel)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23530/what-happened-to-mike-and-carols-former-spouses/78124#78124) to the question [What happened to Mike and Carol's former spouses?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/23530/48608).

The answer is given using multiple sources.

Answer (score 3):

I am nomination LeonX's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78623/1190) to my own question [What is the symbolism behind the colour change of characters while thinking?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23937/what-is-the-symbolism-behind-the-colour-change-of-characters-while-thinking)

Getting answer after 2 years and also with someone who paid attention to every single feedback deserve the appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

I am nominating Napoleon Wilson's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/was-ras-al-ghul-nearly-immortal-in-the-dark-knight-trilogy/77765#77765) to [Was Ra's al Gaul nearly immortal in the Dark Knight Trilogy?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/was-ras-al-ghul-nearly-immortal-in-the-dark-knight-trilogy)

The answer completely answered the question as well as providing credible sources.

Answer (score 2):

I am nominating Sinister's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75853/why-is-the-movie-titled-the-rum-diary/75865#75865) to [Why is the movie titled "The Rum Diary"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75853/why-is-the-movie-titled-the-rum-diary)

This answer was well written and provided sources. Sinister also  graciously accepted additional information provided by other users for the sake of providing a good answer. This is a great example of the community working together for the benefit of the site!

Answer (score 2):

I am nominating Walt's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/why-are-portraits-of-david-crockett-and-sam-houston-on-wall-in-naked-gun/79635#79635) to [Why are portraits of David Crockett and Sam Houston on wall in Naked Gun?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/79633/why-are-portraits-of-david-crockett-and-sam-houston-on-wall-in-naked-gun)

A credible source directly from the filmmaker was given to another well written and informative answer by Walt.