# Favourite questions and answers from the 3rd quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

We'd once again ask the community for their favourite questions and answers from the past quarter. So **please link to your favorite questions and answers which were created from July 1st 2017 through September 30th 2017.**

You can use the search to find all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2017-07..2017-09) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2017-07..2017-09). Since we currently get ~1.2k/1.8k questions/answers per quarter, here are some data queries to help with the decision making process:

- [Questions with most views from 3rd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288)
- [Questions with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289)
- [Answers with most votes from 3rd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290)

But those are really just hints, feel free to mention any question or answer you really enjoyed. There's also no requirement to only mention one post per meta answer, since this is **not a contest** of any kind. Just list as many and whatever posts you want. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the apreciation they deserved.

And if you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also **nominate it in the [corresponding answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4008/49)**.

Answer (score 4):

All these questions and answers are my favorite ones.

1. [Catija](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/16420/catija)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78384/27264) to [**How exactly are subtitles and closed captions written for movies?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78383/27264) that shares quite nice details about subtitles that I was curious about.
2. [Paulie_D](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34317/paulie-d)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78107/27264) to [**Why did John Doe appear as press photographer?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78105/27264).
3. [Gnemlock](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/47313/gnemlock)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/76133/27264) to [**Has an actor ever played a woman, or an actress a man, in a non-comedic/horror way?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/76128/27264) asked by [Ghoti and Chips](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42655/ghoti-and-chips).
4. [Sinister](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48608/sinister)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/75865/27264) to [**Why is the movie titled "The Rum Diary"?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75853/27264) asked by [Chris Elvis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/53425/chris-elvis). He gave a nice explanation of this movie title.
5. And last my own [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/80525/27264) to the question [**How did they film the walks between the Twin Towers in The Walk?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/80524/27264). It includes each detail about how this scene was filmed from different sources.