# Favourite questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

A happy new year to all! As done [3 months ago](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4014/48608), We would ask the community again to **link your favorite questions and answers created from 1st October 2017 to 31st December 2017**

You can search all the eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2017-10..2017-12) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+created%3A2017-10..2017-12) posted the past quarter. Since we got 1.1 k questions and 1.5 k answers in the past quarter, to make your job easier, here are some data queries.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the fourth quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the fourth quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the fourth quarter](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2017/10/01)

The above ones are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answered you enjoyed. Since this is **not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself but which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.

If you feel one of the answers written this quarter even deserves additional credit in the form of a reputation bounty, feel free to also nominate it in the corresponding **[answer reward contest](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4136/48608)**.

Answer (score 6):

All these questions and answers are my favorite ones.

1. [MattD](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/5733/mattd)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/81023/27264) to [**Is the loudness of a movie in the theater set by the theater or by the publisher/studio?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81022/27264) asked by [Tyler Durden](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/11216/tyler-durden). Both question and answer are my favorite.
2. [Steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/steelersquirrel)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83267/27264) to [**What's the significance of the shooting star in Jaws?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83266/27264).
3. [LevenTrek](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/57106/leventrek)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83814/27264) to [**Admiral Holdo's tactic in “Star Wars: The Last Jedi” - Why is this not used more?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83749/27264) asked by [chb](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/60053/chb). Both Q&A are my favorite.
4. [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83534/27264) to [**Why is the title “The Karate Kid” when they are using Kung fu?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83531/27264) asked by [Plexus](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/53395/plexus).
5. [Snow](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43022/snow)'s [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83165/27264) to [**How are the face cuts done when Dexter takes his blood samples of his victims?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83163/27264) asked by [Jared](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/749/jared).
6. And last my own [**answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/82916/27264) to the question [**What is the Supergerm in the Justice League film?**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82914/27264) asked by [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma). It happens to come from a piece of image I remembered.

Answer (score 6):

**FAVORITE QUESTIONS:**

1. yuritsuki's [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81029/whats-the-value-of-the-john-wick-gold-coins) "What's the value of the John Wick gold coins?"
2. Lars Mekes [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82223/how-is-michael-myers-bulletproof) "How is Michael Myers bulletproof?"
3. Nathan Reed's [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82621/why-does-the-ark-burn-the-markings-off-its-crate) "Why does the Ark burn the markings off its crate?"
4. Nog Shine's [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82773/what-were-the-rats-eating-near-the-cave) "What were the rats eating near the cave?"
5. Memor-X [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82828/what-does-baa-ram-ewe-actually-do) "What does Baa-ram-ewe actually do?"
6. Sudip Biswas [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83291/two-different-cameos-of-martin-scorsese-in-taxi-driver) "Two different cameos of Martin Scorsese in Taxi Driver?"
7. Mark Rogers [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84171/has-a-major-film-ever-intentionally-used-live-ammunition-to-film-a-scene) "Has a major film ever intentionally used live ammunition to film a scene?"

Answer (score 5):

**FAVORITE ANSWERS:**

1. Adam John's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/whats-the-deal-with-the-bullets/81933#81933) to "What's the Deal with the Bullets?"
2. Darth Locke's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/47452/how-did-hannibal-become-the-type-of-cannibal-he-is/83380#83380) to "How did Hannibal become the type of cannibal he is?
3. Paulie_D's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82246/why-is-there-a-horse-skeleton-in-the-2005-movie-sahara/82248#82248) to "Why is there a horse skeleton in the 2005 movie Sahara?
4. DForck42's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82385/what-was-the-purpose-of-saitos-presence-during-the-inception-job/82387#82387) to "What was the purpose of Saito's presence during the inception job?
5. ashik's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82394/how-does-jeepers-creepers-3-fit-in-to-the-timeline/82401#82401) to "How does Jeepers Creepers 3 fit in to the timeline?"
6. userLTK's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82536/is-doctor-hill-a-cult-member/82950#82950) to "Is Doctor Hill a cult member?"
7. Sudip Biswas [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83511/why-is-tommy-shooting-at-the-fourth-wall/83515#83515) to "Why is Tommy shooting at the fourth wall?"
8. Thunderforge's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84058/what-makes-die-hard-a-christmas-movie/84060#84060) to "What makes Die Hard a Christmas movie?"
9. Charles [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83695/is-bills-son-intended-to-be-autistic/84293#84293) to "Is Bill's son intended to be autistic?"