# Rewards for the best answer from the 4th quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, answers

In continuation of [quarterly rewards for the  best answer](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4008/1190) and parallel to our [favorite questions/answers poll](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4104/1190), I'd ask the community again for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward of appreciation:

**Please link to an answer which was created from October 1st 2017 through December 31st 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple entries submit individual answers for each post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- [Answers with most votes from 4th quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/795589/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range-for-the-reward?StartDate=2017-10-01&Count=1200)

Otherwise you can chose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight or needed more appreciation. Answer can be from you or from anyone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 300 points after completion of the event on 21st February 2017.

<sub>Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only.</sub>

---

## Results:-

**Winner - [DForck42](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/82387/1190)

1st Runner-up - [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83799/1190)

2nd Runner-up - [Memor-X](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85087/1190)**

Happy answering and thanks for making it successful again and expecting more participation from next time onward. Feel free to provide suggestion for future.

Comment: **Note about the lock:** This question has been locked due to the voting period having ended. The lock message is however inaccurate in that it is not considered a bad or inappropriate question. It is merely locked for historical preservation of the poll

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DForck42's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82385/what-was-the-purpose-of-saitos-presence-during-the-inception-job/82387#82387) to "What was the purpose of Saito's presence during the inception job?"**

This provided an answer to the question with quotes and an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate [steelersquirrel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792/steelersquirrel)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83799/27264) to [Straight Outta Compton - claims of police abuse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57467/27264)

This answer is detailed and well-researched to tell the historical accuracy of a show.

Answer (score 5):

Memor-X's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85087/1190) to [Why does Simba get respect from animals of Pride Lands even when he eats them?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85081/why-does-simba-get-respect-from-animals-of-pride-lands-even-when-he-eats-them)

This answer show the deep analysis of movie and using film quotes to support the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Sudip Biswas [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83511/why-is-tommy-shooting-at-the-fourth-wall/83515#83515) to "Why is Tommy shooting at the fourth wall?"**

This answer provided quotes and a source from the director of the film.

Answer (score 2):

**userLTK's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82536/is-doctor-hill-a-cult-member/82950#82950) to "Is Doctor Hill a cult member?"**

This answer provided a detailed explanation accompanied with sources and quotes.  This answer also did not get the recognition that it deserved.

Answer (score 2):

Edlothiad's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/83726/1190) to [How did Leia manage this feat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83719/how-did-leia-manage-this-feat)

It got lack of attention then it deserved and it's nice to see a competing answer which outsmart your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**ashik's [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/82394/how-does-jeepers-creepers-3-fit-in-to-the-timeline/82401#82401) to "How does Jeepers Creepers 3 fit in to the timeline?"**

This answer completely explained the timeline as well as providing sources.  This answer also did not get the recognition that it deserved.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Obie 2.0](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/34478/obie-2-0)'s [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/82329/27264) to [Why didn't the scientists in Stranger Things recognise this place?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82236/27264)

This answer provides all possibilities that can come from good knowledge about the show.